# sending http requests with specific http version protocol in ruby

Tags: ruby, http, version

There is some way to send http requests in ruby with specific http version protocol.

I use net/http but the default (probably hardcoded) version is 1.1.

Is some way to turn to 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting `Net::HTTP::HTTPVersion` (defaults to `'1.1'`) seems to work:

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.send(:remove_const, :HTTPVersion) # avoid warning
Net::HTTP::HTTPVersion = '1.0'

http = Net::HTTP.new('example.com')
http.set_debug_output($stdout)
http.get('/')
```

Output:

```
<- "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: Ruby\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n"
-> "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
-> "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: max-age=604800\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
-> ...
```

A `GET / HTTP/1.0` is sent and the server answers with `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`. Note that HTTP/1.1 headers (e.g. `Host: example.com`) are still present.